# Rails routing to nested controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have one controller for creating category, and I want to have one more nested controller to create language versions of categories. I want to avoid methods like `new_language, edit_language, ...` and routing on them, I would like to do it the best rails way. But I am new to rails (from Padrino and Sinatra), and I am little bit lost in routing.

I have my controller for categories

```
module Admin
  class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :find_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

    layout 'admin'

    def index
      @categories = Category.all
    end

    ..... all the others CRUD methods ....

  end
end
```

And another controller.

```
module Admin
  class CategoriesLanguageController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :find_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

    def new
      @category = Category.find(params[:category].to_i)
    end

    .... all the others CRUD methods ...

  end
end
```

and my routes config.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
  namespace :admin do
    get '/' => 'dashboard#index'
    resources :dashboard, only: [:index]
    resources :categories do
      collection do
        get :publish_category
        #get :new_lang
        #post :create_lang
        #get :edit
        #post :update
        #get :destroy
      end
      resources :language, only: [:new, :create, :edit]
    end
  end

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root to: "homepage#index"

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :categories, only: [:index]
    end
  end


end
```

I would like to have methods `new_lang and create_lang` under second controller with default names `new, create, ...`.

It generates this

```
                                                admin GET    /admin(.:format)                                                                                  admin/dashboard#index
                   admin_dashboard_index GET    /admin/dashboard(.:format)                                                                        admin/dashboard#index
       publish_category_admin_categories GET    /admin/categories/publish_category(.:format)                                                      admin/categories#publish_category
           admin_category_language_index POST   /admin/categories/:category_id/language(.:format)                                                 admin/language#create
             new_admin_category_language GET    /admin/categories/:category_id/language/new(.:format)                                             admin/language#new
            edit_admin_category_language GET    /admin/categories/:category_id/language/:id/edit(.:format)                                        admin/language#edit
                        admin_categories GET    /admin/categories(.:format)                                                                       admin/categories#index
                                         POST   /admin/categories(.:format)                                                                       admin/categories#create
                      new_admin_category GET    /admin/categories/new(.:format)                                                                   admin/categories#new
                     edit_admin_category GET    /admin/categories/:id/edit(.:format)                                                              admin/categories#edit
                          admin_category GET    /admin/categories/:id(.:format)                                                                   admin/categories#show
                                         PATCH  /admin/categories/:id(.:format)                                                                   admin/categories#update
                                         PUT    /admin/categories/:id(.:format)                                                                   admin/categories#update
                                         DELETE /admin/categories/:id(.:format)                                                                   admin/categories#destroy
```

but it is not working.

`ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Admin::Categories#index`

and error is this route:

`<td><%= link_to cat.internal_name, edit_admin_category_language_path(id: cat) %></td>`

And I don't know how to create these actions in another controller and use url helpers.

Or this is not the best way to do it?

Please any advice?

Comment: All looks ok to me, add more details about the error you're getting and add the code around where the error happens.

Comment: `@category = Category.find(params[:category].to_i)` should be `@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])`